# Soldier returns home, brings war with him

Tags: story-identification

It features a high ranking officer who has battled across the centuries in some sort of galactic war and now, worn out and jaded, wants to retire or return back in time to his home village. Against all advice he returns to his village and unwittingly drags a bit of the war with him. He notices his peaceful village is being harassed by bullies, who turn out to be werewolves and other supernaturals whom he had been battling all along in the future war. In a fierce street fight he disposes of them, realizes his duty and returns to his troops on the frontline of the future war.

Any ideas who wrote this or what it's called? It seems like it was part of a series or a balloon for a series. It was neatly written in the style of the eighties or nineties. Thx!

Comment: probably duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132120/need-help-identifying-short-story-about-retired-military-colonel-who-fought-war/132135 (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 15):

I believe you are looking for "A Dry, Quiet War" by Tony Daniel. You can find it in "The Best of the Best: 20 Years of The Year's Best Science Fiction." G. Dozois introduces the story with...

> "In 'A Dry, Quiet War,' he spins a colorful and exotic story of a battle-weary veteran who returns from a bewilderingly strange high-tech future war only to  face his greatest and most sinister challenge right at home..."

It is an exceptionally good story; As it would have to be, to be in the Best of the Best. :)

Comment: It is indeed a good yarn. Also anthologiezed in *Future War* I belive, though my copy is in storage just now.