# Col. Henry Bone

Tags: story-identification

What story features Col. Henry Bone at the end of the universe, with all remaining creatures fighting in deadly earnest over all scraps?  There seems to be something of a western theme, as well as a character who/which does not recognize Col. Bone in time before making a fatal mistake.

Comment: "A Dry, Quiet War"? It has been answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/132120/51379).

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate because the OP [left a (non) answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/159460/51379) on the duplicate question indicating that it was what they were looking for.