# Another Sci-Fi mystery?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This short story is one that I may have encountered in the 90s editions of "Asimov's" magazine. Unfortunately, I am vague about the exact details.

A soldier returns to his own time from a horrendous battle in the distant future (he was on the winning side). He has been altered so that he is able to perceive across multiple dimensions/time lines. He enters a bar/tavern/eatery and witnesses another "veteran" (or being) abusing/threatening a woman he cares (cared) about. He is forced to kill this abuser across every dimension/time line he exists in, to protect this woman. In doing so, he must return to the future and fight in the war all over again.

Comment: My understanding is we only close story ID questions as duplicated if both have an accepted answer?

Comment: @Skooba - That is indeed true. I've used my dupehammer to open it again.

Comment: I'd be quite interested to know why Yasskier, Gallifreian, Himarm, Mithrandir and CBredlow voted to close this question given that I know for certain that at least three of those users are very well aware of [the agreed policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774)

Comment: @Valorum:  Can we have a link to the other questions that it was (not) a duplicate of?

Comment: @Buzz The edit history shows that the question was closed as a duplicate of [Need help identifying short story about retired military colonel who fought war at end of time](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132120/need-help-identifying-short-story-about-retired-military-colonel-who-fought-war).

Comment: @Buzz - Related links always come up on the right as "Linked" → → →

Comment: @Buzz - You can also see the timeline here; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/148074/timeline

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to look at the linked posts, because the link was no longer extant.

Comment: @Valorum ;-).  I posted that when it came up in review queue. You would think that if the VTC users *really* thought it was, they could have posted the same story here and maybe gotten a couple rep points!

Comment: @Skooba - I'll post it as a CW if no-one else does it before this evening

Answer (score 7):

This sounds an awful lot like "[A Dry, Quiet War](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45612)" (1996) by Tony Daniel, which has previously been asked about and answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132120/need-help-identifying-short-story-about-retired-military-colonel-who-fought-war/132135) (where it was accepted) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28451/soldier-returns-home-brings-war-with-him/28453) (where it was not, but there are no other answers offered).

The story can be [read in its entirety online](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/quietwar.htm) at InfinityPlus, so it should be easy enough to check. It does indeed feature a soldier of a future war in an altercation with another veteran over a woman, with multi-dimensional combat:

> "Colonel Bone," he began. "If I'd knowed it was you­­"
>
> "Too late for that."
>
> "It's never too late, that's what you taught us all when you turned
> that offensive around out on the Husk and gave the Chaos the what-for.
> I'll just be going. I'll take the gang with me. It's to no purpose,
> our staying now."
>
> "You knew enough yesterday ­­ enough to leave." I felt the rage, the
> old rage that was to be, once again. "Why did you do that to her?" I
> asked. "Why did you ­­ "
>
> And then I looked into his eyes and saw it there. The quiet desire ­­
> beaten down by synthesized emotions, but now triumphant, sadly
> triumphant. The desire to finally, finally die. Marek was not the
> unthinking brute I'd taken him for after all. Too bad for him.
>
> I took a step toward Marek. His instincts made him reach down, go for
> the trunch. But it was a useless weapon on me. I don't have myelin
> sheaths on my nerves. I don't have nerves anymore; I have wiring.
> Marek realized this was so almost instantly. He dropped the trunch,
> then turned and ran. I caught him. He tried to fight, but there was
> never any question of him beating me. That would be absurd. I'm
> Colonel Bone of the Skyfalling 8th. I kill so that there might be
> life. Nobody beats me. It is my fate, and yours, too.
>
> I caught him by the shoulder, and I looped my other arm around his
> neck and reined him to me ­­ not enough to snap anything. Just enough
> to calm him down. He was strong, but had no finesse.
>
> Like I said, glims are hard to kill. They're the same as snails in
> shells in a way, and the trick is to draw them out ­­ way out. Which
> is what I did with Marek. As I held him physically, I caught hold of
> him, all of him, over there, in the place I can't tell you about,
> can't describe. The way you do this is by holding a glim still and
> causing him great suffering, so that they can't withdraw into the deep
> places. That's what vampire stakes and Roman crosses are all about.
>
> And like I told Bex, glims are bad ones, all right. Bad, but not the
> worse. I am the worse.

and, due to this, he must return to fight the war again:

> Irrevocably gone from this time line, and that was what mattered.
> Keeping this possible future uncertain, balanced on the fulcrum of
> chaos and necessity. Keeping it free, so that I could go back and do
> my work...
>
> I went to the living room, to the shroud-covered furniture. I sat down
> in what had been my father's chair. I sipped a cup of my father's best
> barley malt whisky. I sat, and as the suns of Ferro rose in the hard
> iron sky, I faded into the distant, dying future.